# How to send a message with InlineKeyboardMarkup and ReplyKeyboardRemove at the same time?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I've got a case, when a user clicks a button on a custom keyboard, and I want the bot to send a reply message with an inline keyboard, and, at the same time, remove the custom keyboard, because it's become redundant.

According to the [SendMessage API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), `reply_markup` should be one of the following:

- [InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup)
- [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup)
- [ReplyKeyboardRemove](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove)
- [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply)

So I can't send a combination of InlineKeyboardMarkup and ReplyKeyboardRemove.

I've also tried to send a message with ReplyKeyboardRemove, and then make another request of [EditMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) type, but it fails with

```json
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 400,
    "description": "Bad Request: message can't be edited"
}
```

That's described a bit in [Updating messages section](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages):

> Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages without reply_markup or with inline keyboards.

I'm currently struggling how can I achieve the goal, probably with some workaround?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't combine these. You would need to send two separate messages, each with different `reply_markup`.